# Retrieving data from sqlite with python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to make a python file that connect to my small database that will retrieve the temperature and humidity depending on the date and time set in an html form.

```
  <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#dateValue" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form name="myForm" method="post" action="/cgi-bin/script1.py">
    <p>Date: <input type="text" name="dateValue" id="dateValue"></p>
    <p>Time: <select name="timeValue" id="timeValue">
      <option value="0">--All Day--</option>
      <option value="01">1am</option>
      <option value="02">2am</option>
      <option value="03">3am</option>
      <option value="04">4am</option>
      <option value="05">5am</option>
      <option value="06">6am</option>
      <option value="07">7am</option>
      <option value="08">8am</option>
      <option value="09">9am</option>
      <option value="10">10am</option>
      <option value="11">11am</option>
      <option value="12">12am</option>
      <option value="13">1pm</option>
      <option value="14">2pm</option>
      <option value="15">3pm</option>
      <option value="16">4pm</option>
      <option value="17">5pm</option>
      <option value="18">6pm</option>
      <option value="19">7pm</option>
      <option value="20">8pm</option>
      <option value="21">9pm</option>
      <option value="22">10pm</option>
      <option value="23">11pm</option>
      <option value="24">12pm</option>
     </select>
      <input type="submit" value="Enter"/>
    </form>
```

so once they input that data they are supposed to connect to a database which the name is readings.db and connect to the table weather which has the structure

ID
dateReading
timeReading
temperature
humidity

How do I connect to the database retrieve only the temperature and humidity for the date and time selected in the form. and how do i make it so if they chose 10am it selects all temperatures and humidity within 10am so from 10am to 11am type thing. and if there is no date or time in the database for that time then it says No data Found for the date and time.

This is my script so far

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys 
import cgi, cgitb 

form = cgi.FieldStorage() 

dateValue = form.getvalue('dateValue')
timeValue  = form.getvalue('timeValue')

con = lite.connect('readings.db')

with con:
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute('SELECT temperature, humidity FROM weather WHERE dateReading = dataValue AND timeReading = timeValue')

rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:
    print row

print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n"
print "<html>"
print "<head>"
print "<title>Hello - CGI Program</title>"
print "</head>"
print "<body>"
print "<h2>received from the form %s %s</h2>" % (dateValue, timeValue)
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

The last litte bit is more of a test to make sure i was getting the data from the form

Comment: It rather depends how how the data is stored in the database, if it's in datetime format you are going to have convert the selected datevalue into the same type before you can use it. It would probably help if you showed the database schema (structure) for the table `weather` and say if the datevalue is a python datetime object or at least show us how it is represented. Clearly the time is a numeric string.

Comment: The data in the database is structured the same way that it is received by the form

Comment: In the database is `dateReading` defined as `datetime`, `int`, `text` etc and is `timeReading` defined as `int`, `float`, `text`? It matters because you have to compare like with like. For the input data try printing out the value of `type(dateValue)` and `type(timeValue)` which will tell you how they are being received. Once you know the data types of the 2 items in the input data and in the database, you will have a fighting chance of achieving your goal.

Comment: time and date are both text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments as long as the input text has the same format as the text object in the database, then the date is what it is.
Your only issue is time. I suggest that you convert the inputTime to an integer, add 1 to it and then convert it back to a string.

```
use_time = int(inputTime)
finish_time = use_time + 1
start_time = str(use_time)
finish_time = str(finish_time)
```

then your select statement would look like this:

```
cur.execute('SELECT temperature, humidity FROM weather WHERE dateReading = dateValue and timeReading >= start_time and timeReading < finish_time')
```